# Create Azure Windows VM using another language version

Tags: windows, azure

Is it possible to choose another language beside US-EN, during Azure VM creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never had to do it myself but here's a [link](http://coding.abel.nu/2014/02/add-a-language-to-windows-azure-visual-studio-vm/) that explain how to install a language pack **after** the installation.

> Open the control panel and select “Add a language”. Find the language
>   you want to add and add it. Now it is available for selection as input
>   locale etc, but the translation files needed to get exception messages
>   in the language are not automatically downloaded. That can be done by
>   selecting the “options” link. Select “Download and Install Language
>   Pack” to continue.